# get calculation from two table with one query

Tags: mysql

I have two tables one is job and second one is applied_job, I want count result with one query, Please look into this

```
job table                       job_applied table
-------------------------      -------------------------------------
j_id| job_title | salary       a_id   | applied_id | status | job_id
-------------------------      -------------------------------------
234 | PHP       | 50           2342   | 2          | 1      | 127 
235 | Ruby      | 102          2362   | 4          | 2      | 127 
127 | Python    | 150          2322   | 5          | 2      | 127 
1289| Java      | 180          2326   | 6          | 2      | 127
1274| .net      | 180          123    | 8          | 3     | 127

status 1 = selected
status 2 = rejected
status 3 = onhold
```

Now I want the result like this with one query

```
j_id  applied_count  rejected_count onhold_count selected
234   0              0              0            0
235   0              0              0            0 
127   5              3              1            1
1289  0              0              0            0
1274  0              0              0            0
```

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: "I want the result like this". What are the rules by which you arrive at this desired result? There could be many ways to achieve it, but they might not do what you want when the data is different. And also, what have you researched and attempted so far? This isn't a free write-all-my-code service, so please show what code you have tried to write, and explain what the problem is with it (e.g., you get an error, or the result is wrong). Then you will get a much better response from the SO community :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is a combination of `left join`, `group by` and `case`:

```
select  t1.j_id,
        count(*) as applied_count
        sum(case when t2.status = 2 then 1 end) rejected_count,
        sum(case when t2.status = 3 then 1 end) onhold_count,
        sum(case when t2.status = 1 then 1 end) selected_count
from    job t1
left join
        job_applied t2
on      t1.j_id = t2.job_id
group by t1.j_id
```

All the fields in the resulting set are already available on `job_applied`, but you need that table to joined with `job` because you want all the available jobs, even if there's no job_applied row associated.

Comment: count(job_id) as applied_count, Please change this In Query:)

Comment: That would be wrong, because all the counts would be 1. You maybe meant `count(a_id)`, but that wouldn't make any difference, the result in this case would be exactly the same as `count(*)`